# Get service IP:PORT as environment variable in pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a `service` running and attached to a pod. In the pod, I need to define `env` variable which has to point to itself. If I run locally, I would set `path` to `localhost:8080` and it works. How can I set `env` variable to point to the service itself?

```
user@user % kubectl get svc
NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)             AGE
my-service           LoadBalancer   10.96.116.26   129.153.28.245    8080:31495/TCP      21h
kubernetes           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>            443/TCP,12250/TCP   5d18h
```

If the configuration is:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp   
        image: path/to/imageregistry/image:v1.0.0-amd64
        env:
          - name: BASE_PATH
            value: "129.153.28.245:8080"
```

App is working, in a sense that If I open in browser `129.153.28.245:8080/app/pages` it will open the website. If I replace `<EXTERTNAL-IP>` with `<CLUSTER-IP>` it's not loading.

How to retrieve `<EXTERTNAL-IP>` from the `service` and put into `env` variable, something like:

```
env:
    - name: BASE_PATH
      value: "<EXTERNAL-IP-FROM-SERVICE-NAME>:8080"
```

or is there another and better approach to do that?

Here's the full `Deployment` and `Service` `yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp    
        image: xxx.ocir.io/xxxxxx/myrepo/myimage:v1.0.0-amd64
        env:
          - name: BASE_PATH
            value: "129.153.28.245:8080"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: ocirsecret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp
```

Comment: Probably, you can use container command to kubectl describe your service to get ip address and export as env variable ?

Comment: Are you working in Kubernetes Open Source, GCP, AWS, Azure?

Comment: @HectorMartinezRodriguez it is OKE (oracle cloud k8s)

Comment: @Mr.Mister. why do you want to do that? It is helpful to include the objective of your deployment in the question so the community can give you a solution that best fits it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Exposing Pod and Cluster Vars to Containers

Let's say you need some data about the Pod or K8s environment in your application to add Pod information as metadata to logs. such as e.g.

- Pod IP
- Pod Namespace
- Service Account of Pod
- But how to access this information?

  - All Pod information can be made available in the config file
- There are 2 ways to expose Pod fileds to a running Container:

  1. Environment Variables
  2. Volume Files

---

##### Environment Variable

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-env
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
        - name: log-sider
          image: busybox
          command: [ 'sh', '-c' ]
          args:
            - while true; do
              echo sync app logs;
              printenv POD_NAME POD_IP POD_SERVICE_ASCCOUNT;
              sleep 20;
              done;
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: POD_SERVICE_ASCCOUNT
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
```

---

- [Source](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#exposing-pod-and-cluster-vars-to-containers)